# Woocommerce specific product template for product type

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I am creating woocommerce based custom plugin and i have created a product type "Poster Product"
Now i want to create a specific product template for poster product and the template should be created and controlled by the plugin itself

Please help and thanks in advance